STM32H7S3L8 measuring HAL_Delay(20) with basic timers TIM6 and TIM7
I am trying to set up timers on STM32H7S3L8.
Here is clock configuration:
I am using TIM6 and TIM7 and as I understand both of them get clock source equal to 300MHz.
I have set their prescalers equal to 300-1.
Here is simple code to measure HAL_Delay(20) and HAL_Delay(30):

When I debug the program in live expressions I get timer_value1 = 6613 and timer_value2 = 11093.
I think I should be getting around 30000 and 50000.
Could you tell me what the problem is?

Have you set the timers' auto reload register (ARR) to the maximal value? i.e. 65535

Auto-reload preload is disabled.

The preload is a different functionality and is not important here. Your timers will count from 0 to the autoreload value and then start over from 0 (or vice versa depending on the count direction). So you need to ensure that the value is large enough for your application.

I see, thank you for explanation. Yes, ARR is set to max 65535 and Counter Mode is Up.

Ok then your timers should be set up correctly and you should get the results you are expecting. How do you debug the code? Please make sure that yo do not have any breakpoints before or between the HAL_Delay() function calls because the timers don't stop when you hit a breakpoint! If your only breakpoint is on the line for timer_value3 you should get your expected result. Otheriwse there is some misconfiguration in systick.

I do not have breakpoints. I just observed values in live expression tab. Should I add breakpoints at values I want to observe?

I usually don't work with live expresdions. You can try with a breakpoint and see if the result changes but it shouldn't
